# what is this white thing that is attached to the small stems and leaves of this guvava tree?

Tags: identification, pest-control

[image]

Location is southern parts of india. They have a white wedge like appearance and black spot on the center.

I would like to know what these are and how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are scales (insects). They have a shell to protect them. They eat sap, and let ant also to eat sap. On some cases ants will take care of them (they are a sort of livestock of ants), in order to get sap. For these two reasons, you find very often ants near scales.

Remove them by hand (I use grass), and water the tree (especially where there were scales): this will water down sap, and so this will not attract ants.  Note: you should remove both the large and the small ones (4 large, and 6 or more small, in your photo).

There are also some chemical pest controls: many are normally not used: they will enter the sap, so you can make fruits not edible for many weeks, and the damages are very often very limited. An other option (but I doubt it is valid in India): winter oil (specific for plant): this will make a layer of oil, which block respiration and so it will kill all insects. But this should be used only then plants are "sleeping" (no leaves).